# ZipArchive PHP - Prevenir 504 al generar archivo

Tags: php, ajax, zip

Estoy generando un archivo Zip de imagenes, el archivo en total pesa 600MB, mi problema es que al momento de generarlo me tira un error `504 (Gateway Timeout)` Mi codigo PHP es el siguiente:

```
if ($zip->open($public_dir . '/' . $zipFileName, ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE) {
    foreach($imagenes as $imagen){
        $zip->addEmptyDir('NewFolder');

            $zip->addFile($route.$imagen, 'NewFolder/'.$file);

        }  
    }
    $zip->close();
}
```

Ajax.

```
$.ajax({
     url: 'https://...',
     type: 'GET',
     cache: false,
     beforeSend: function(){
        swal("Generando ...", {
            buttons: ["Entiendo"],
            allowOutsideClick: false,
            closeOnClickOutside: false
        });
     },
     success: function(file_route_name){
         swal.close()
         window.open(route+'/'+file_route_name)
     }
});
```

Alguien sabe como puedo prevenir el error **504** ya intente utilizar `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);` y aun así no me funciona. ¿Que seria lo más correcto?

Comment: Saludos puedes usar algo así: "ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);"..recuerda que esto debe estar al inicio de tu script  php

Comment: Si no tienes acceso al php.ini donde podrias modificar el limite de memoria. Podrías usar un proceso en segundo plano con exec de php donde se haga el ZIP.